# Exclude classes from scct in gradle

Tags: gradle, scct

How can I exclude classes from being covered by scct?

I have a couple of classes residing in some specific folder that I want to not be covered by scala coverage tool. Actually I don't want them to be excluded at all, just from scct.

Comment: How are you integrating with scct?

Comment: You mean a build tool? Gradle

Comment: No, I mean how you use scct from Gradle. Do you use a third-party scct Gradle plugin? Or an Ant task? Or do you invoke scct with an `Exec` or `JavaExec` task?

Comment: I run a task `gradle checkScct`. There is a gradle-scct plugin